# Is there any method that enables us to observe the 3D large-scale spatial distribution of the dark matter?

Tags: observational-astronomy, cosmology, dark-matter, gravitational-lensing

1. Can we get the three-dimensional spatial distribution of dark matter through gravitational lensing?
2. If not, is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

At scales much larger than individual galaxies or clusters, the most straightforward approach is to simply study the distribution of galaxies. Galaxies trace the large-scale dark matter distribution, and although they are biased tracers, that bias [has been studied extensively](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.09787).